# Openstack octavia : database initialization

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

I am trying to set up Octavia load balancer. I installed the Octavia python package and fired up Octavia-api. When I try openstack loadbalancer list, I get the following error in my Octavia-api log

```
    DBError: (pymysql.err.InternalError) (1054, u"Unknown column 'load_balancer.provider' in 'field list'")
```

There appears to be an initialization issue with the loadbalancer database. How should it be initialized? I don't have a previous install of lbaasv2 that I am trying to upgrade. This is a fresh install of Octavia. Here is my current script for initializing the db

```
       CREATE DATABASE octavia;
       GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON octavia.* TO 'octavia'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'octavia';
       GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON octavia.* TO 'octavia'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'octavia';
        quit;
```

What should this script be changed to?

Thanks Ranga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a dependency issue, depending on how you installed Octavia.

If you are installing Octavia using pip I would recommend that you apply the appropriate version constrains.

> pip install -c https://git.openstack.org/cgit/openstack/requirements/plain/upper-constraints.txt?stable/pike octavia==1.0.2 --upgrade

Once you have run the above, make sure that the database is initialized properly using.

> octavia-db-manage upgrade